# Weird infill edge problem

Tags: ultimaker-cura, prusa-i3, infill

I'm having this weird issue; for some weird reason, the infill pattern starts separating from the walls and over time, the print becomes a mess. As it separates, it starts to curve, and you get this curved end rather than a pointing edge that touches the wall.

Strangely, for the first 4-5 mm of print (which is a lot of layers), the print goes all OK. Not sure what is the issue here, hardware, temperature settings or something else?

I'm using a Prusa I3 MK3S+ with Cura as slicer and printed it on 210/60 °C hot end/bed temperature with 0.6 mm nozzle (I'm using a 0.4 mm layer height with adjustable layer height, but that didn't kick in yet, the print is a very simple box). The filament is eSun PLA+.

[image: Issue with the infill edges]

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! It looks like it is cutting the corners (it either cuts the corner or deposition is not optimal so that it drags the filament). What speed did you use (same as for 0.4 mm)? Furthermore, fitting a larger nozzle diameter should be accompanied with a lower speed (for the same speed as for a 0.4 mm nozzle, fitting a 0.6 mm nozzle would result in a higher extrusion volume). Try lowering the print speed and comment. If this works we can answer your question.

Comment: I'm using default settings in CURA for this nozzle size - interestingly, it does not happen right away. As if at some point, it starts cutting corners, and then it gets progressively worse, and at some point it starts to skip, breaks apart etc.

Comment: Default settings doesn't say much, what speeds are you using?

Comment: it is 60mm/s - the same as for the rest of the print. The extrusion width is 0.6 (100%)

Comment: Try again with 40 mm/s (e.g. 0.4 mm width at 0.2 mm layer height at 60 mm/s will give about 5 cubic mm per second, a 0.6 mm width at 0.4 mm layer height at 60 mm/s will give about 15 cubic mm per second, that may be too much, 40 mm/s reduces to 10 cubic mm per second maybe reduce the layer height as well to 0.3 mm)